# iText, insert new blank line inside PdfPTable column

Tags: java, itext, pdfptable

How do I insert a new blank line inside a `PdfPTable` column. `\n` and `n number of spaces` has not done the trick for me. This is the java code I am working with.

```
chtbc_report1_table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
new Object [][] {
    {"H.B.G", "Some Value", "lbs/kg", "Adult M : 120lbs \n Adult F : 90lbs"},
    .....
    .....
    //Other rows
    },
new String [] {
    "Investigation", "Result", "Unit", "Weight"
}
));
```

I want to put a `new line` between "Adult M : 120lbs `**\n**` Adult F : 90lbs"

**UPDATE**

This is the code I have used for creating a `PdfPTable`

```
document.open();

    PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(chtbc_report1_table.getColumnCount());    
    for (int rows = 0; rows < chtbc_report1_table.getRowCount(); rows++) {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < chtbc_report1_table.getColumnCount(); cols++) {
            pdfTable.addCell(chtbc_report1_table.getModel().getValueAt(rows, cols).toString());

        }
    }
    float[] columnWidths_pdfTable = new float[]{30f, 25f, 40f, 50f};
    pdfTable.setWidths(columnWidths_pdfTable);
    document.add(pdfTable);

document.close()
```

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Can you please share the code where you construct the `PdfPTable` and `PdfPCell` objects? Right now you only show Swing table code.

Comment: Sure, coming right away

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : Updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, that is quite simple indeed. Try the following as the same works for me :-

**Table Contents**

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"Lorem Ipsum", "Next Line here \n, Another new line\n, Two new lines\n\nI will end here"},
            {"Lorem Ipsum", "Another cell to demonstrate \n\n\n\n4 New lines above and two below \n\n"}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Text", "Long Text"
        }
    ));
```

Let me know, if that worked. And the `PdfPtable` should be the same.

Comment: I use `iText 5.5.6` and that worked. So silly that I did not even try that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Go visit the [link](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php). There a lot of examples and lot to learn. Do some R&D before posting in SO.